# How To Play FLV Files?

Tags: windows-vista, software-rec, media-player, flv

Whats the best free video player that will play **.flv** files on my PC?

Answer (score 33):

VLC is definitely the way to go on this one.  It will play almost anything you throw at it.

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html

Comment: Agreed; I've yet to run across a file that makes VLC choke plus I can standardize my video player across platforms.

Answer (score 5):

VLC is the best, and there is also a portable version for USB devices from portableapps.com

Answer (score 4):

Media Player Classic or VLC.

Answer (score 3):

[Media Player Classic Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/).

It has better support for Vista over the older version which has not been updated for over a year.  It is freeware, open source, very snappy and light on resources.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the rest of the known universe, I don't really like VLC, so instead I'm going to suggest mplayer - which I use to play everything.

Comment: worry not, you're not alone :)

Comment: Same here. I'd rather use Media Player Classic for my movie viewing.

Comment: mplayer != MPC :)
http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html

Comment: I agree. In my opinion MPlayer is much superior to VLC as it is not only smaller but also faster and well-conceived. The console interface is just great. It is very easy to learn. You can even play movies in the framebuffer. VLC is slow and bloated while not giving any real benefits. :)

Answer (score 1):

The open source [KMPlayer](http://download.pandora.tv/?mode=kmp&tab=1) will play FLV (along with pretty much everything else) without having to install additional codecs. Looks good too.
It's reviewed on the [Gizmo's Freeware site](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-media-player-replacement.htm).

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) as well as [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) do the job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Desktop-based FLV player:**

Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X, Unix-based
Adobe Media Player (freeware)
Media Player Classic (free software)
MPlayer (free software)
RealPlayer (freeware)
VLC media player (free software)
Winamp (freeware)

Answer (score 0):

[CCCP](http://cccp-project.net) includes all codecs necessary to play FLV files (as well as most popular formats), and also comes with Media Player Classic, which is my favorite player.

Answer (score 0):

[**SMPlayer**](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/) is a free, open source front-end for MPlayer. It plays pretty much any media file under the sun and the subtitle features are superior to any other player.

[image]

A portable version is available [here](http://www.pendriveapps.com/smplayer-portable-media-player/).

Answer (score 0):

VLC's a great open source media player, but for Windows I prefer the **KMPlayer**'s GUI, customization features and overall ease of use than VLC.

Like VLC, it can play almost anything you throw at it (including FLV files).

The KMPlayer in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Multimedia_Player

Note: KMPlayer is a Windows software and is freeware, but not open source.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the previously mentioned really good players (like [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) which does work on very much platforms, and supports very much formats, or [Media Player Classic Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/), which also has 64 bit support), **I can also suggest [BS.Player](http://www.bsplayer.com/)** (with e.g. [Phoenix](http://www.bsplayer.com/bsplayer-english/skin/all-g3/phoenix-s768.html) skin or [Mgc3WMP](http://www.bsplayer.com/bsplayer-english/skin/all-g3/mgc3wmp-v2-5-s766.html) skin, which are very nice).

This player also supports very-very many formats, and its subtitle correction and subtitle appearance customization options are very handy too, which is very important to me when watching films in other languages - in very many players, subtitle appearance customization is too complicated or oversimplified (I know VLC also has this capability, but I think it's a bit over-elaborated...).

It works only on Windows platforms (no Linux or Mac support) for the time being though (Windows 98/ME/2000/XP/Vista/Windows 7), but for Windows it's a really useful media player.

**[Phoenix skin](http://www.bsplayer.com/bsplayer-english/skin/all-g3/phoenix-s768.html)**:

[image]

**[Mgc3WMP skin](http://www.bsplayer.com/bsplayer-english/skin/all-g3/mgc3wmp-v2-5-s766.html)**:

[image]

Comment: I edited in the links for you. Note that as per the [FAQ] you would have to mention any affiliation of a product you're recommending. So if that's the case, please add it.

Comment: @slhck: thanks for editing the post. BUT I don't really understand, why would I have ANY affiliation of this product?! I recommended a product which I personally like, and which I found really easy-to-handle. If you mentioned this rule under my comment, why didn't you do it under all the other comments in this thread too? :) Others also mentioned products THEY PERSONALLY LIKE, similarly to me.

Comment: Then it's perfectly okay, no worries! You wouldn't know, but every day there are quite a few promotional posts (the player you linked to has a paid version, that's why I asked).

Comment: @slhck: OK, thanks for calming me down, I thought someone would rate my comment as a spam or something for suggesting a player I like... :D Personally I use the free version of it, which is totally enough for my purposes. I only suggest the free one, I wouldn't recommend anyone to buy a player when there are perfect free alternatives on the market (like VLC, MPC-HC). :)